# c programming structure to header file

Tags: c

how to get input for structure inside a header file. i am getting an error when trying to ask the user for input in the header file.

```
#include "input.h"
struct planecat{
char seat_Id;   //id num of seat
int seatmark;  //seat availability 
char first_holdr[20]; //first name of the seat holder
char last_holdr[20];  //last name of the seat holder 
};


int main(){ struct planecat aisle[6],window[6];
select_b(aisle,window);}
```

insideheader

```
 void input(struct planecat aisle[6],struct planecat window[6]){
 {
   int i;
   printf("enter name");
   scanf("%i",&aisle[i].first_holdr);}
```

the program is giving me error by`error C2036: 'planecat *' : unknown size`

```
 error C2037: left of 'seatmark' specifies undefined struct/union 'planecat'
```

Comment: how the heck does this compile? there are 2 to few closing brackets. did you copy/paste it all?

Comment: Your struct definition must be before.

Comment: the input function defined in the header, the struct declared in the cpp, after the header uses it..

Comment: Also consider typedef.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put these

```
struct planecat{
char seat_Id;   //id num of seat
int seatmark;  //seat availability 
char first_holdr[20]; //first name of the seat holder
char last_holdr[20];  //last name of the seat holder 
};
```

in the input.h , and before the void input…………

And I advise you to put your definition in your head file, and others in the cpp/c files

Answer (score 0):

Definition should go before usage. You have to place `struct planecat{...}` at the beginning of header file (preferred), or before `#include "input.h"` (bad style).